# How to kmow if a young rose is a climber

Tags: houseplants, flowers, roses, urban-gardening, climbers

I bought this young rose and it already has blooms,  smaller than the regular rose flowers but I noticed that it's kinda growing horizontally and long stems so I put a stick beside it to support its growth.  Just wondering,  could this rose be a climber? How to know if a young rose is a climber? [image]

Comment: there's  no real way of telling whether its a climber, rambler or bush until you see the growth habit - was there no label with the name of the rose when you bought it?